# Xamarin convert ContentPage into Activity

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im trying to use this code in the link below in a Xamarin.Forms Project. So I builded an Interface, but i need something to convert from e.g. ContentPage into Activity.

http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/using-xamarin-auth-oauth2authenticator-with-asyncawait/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Xamarin Forms Dependency Service to accomplish this. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Create a ILogin interface in your PCL and then implement that on each project. You should then be able to call that from you shared code.